# When the user clicks a text box on my form, I need to assign an ID to the current record if there isn't one already

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a form, frmEvent, for editing and creating records. Each record represents an Event. I have a pop-up form that displays the many-to-many relationships that associate one or more Persons to the current Event. This pop-up form is opened when the user clicks a text box on frmEvent.

The pop-up form displays all of the records in tblEventPersons where EventID = the ID of the Event record that is currently open. This normally works great. **However,** when my form is used to create a new Event record, Access does not assign an ID for the new Event record until at least one field has been changed. If a user creates a new Event record and tries to immediately open the frmEventPersons form, they get an error because the new Event record does not yet have an ID assigned.

I'm sure there's a very simple solution to this, but my searches have not yielded anything useful.

Comment: Correct. This is how Access works. No ID is assigned until the record is created. This is because you could cancel the new record before it is saved. If you do `Me.Dirty = False` it will attempt to save the record, creating an ID. Otherwise, you can't move on to the next step until the record is created. Handle the error and instruct the user to finish the record before moving to the next step.

Comment: me.dirty = false will ONLY work if you dirtied the record. If you just moved to a new record as the poster notes, then me.dirty = false will not work since it not yet dirty. the ONLY way to make this work is to set or dirty some bound control/column, and THEN do the me.Dirty = False. If the record is new, and NEVER been dirty, then you can't do a me.dirty = false and it will not force the generation of the autonumber PK unless the record was made dirty at some point in time. The INSTANT the user types in some field, then yes me.dirty  = false will work.

Comment: But, if user does not type anything and clicks on button to launch that form, then they are hooped, and hence the question and perplexing by the poster.  Me.dirty = false, or even docmd.Acsave record from the menu etc. will not work, since there is nothing to save and save does not work until such time the record has become dirty. ONLY way to make this work is as per my code below - the code HAS to dirty something on the form and then the save command (or me.dirty = false) will now work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well it is assumed that the main form has a record, and has some data and has a "ID" as you well asked.

However, if the form is moved to a new record, and you want to launch that next form that requires and needs the current forms ID that as you WELL note has not yet been generated?

Well, keep in mind that you current form WILL IN FACT generate the ID (assuming a auto number PK id column) if the current record has been "dirtied". We thus assume that the current record had SOME data editing. If it has NO EDITING done, then it actauly turns out is a bit of a trick to get Access force feed and generate that ID.

About the MOST easy way?
Dirty some field/column in the current form.
eg:

```
  if isnull(me!ID) then
     ' this record does not yet have the PK id
     ' dirty some bound control.
     me.MyEditDate = date()
  end if

  me.Dirty = false     ' this will force a recrod save - gereate the "ID" you want.

  docmd.Open "frmDetails",,,"FKColumn = " & me!id
```